24.04 LTS installing linux-image 6.8.0-44-generic failed
Simple installation failed here - seems not appreciating evdi module.
I think dependencies are not fully tested
Here is the full log.
sudo apt upgrade
[...]
Paramétrage de python3-distupgrade (1:24.04.23) ...
Paramétrage de libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-0:amd64 (2.44.3-0ubuntu0.24.04.1) ...
Paramétrage de linux-headers-6.8.0-44-generic (6.8.0-44.44) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-44-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-44-generic all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/6.8.0-44-generic/build/include KVERSION=6.8.0-44-generic DKMS_BUILD=1...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for evdi: 1.10.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-44-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.10.1/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-44-generic/x86_64 failed for evdi(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-44-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet linux-headers-6.8.0-44-generic (--configure) :
 le sous-processus paquet linux-headers-6.8.0-44-generic script post-installation installé a renvoyé un état de sortie d'erreur 11
Paramétrage de libjavascriptcoregtk-6.0-1:amd64 (2.44.3-0ubuntu0.24.04.1) ...
Paramétrage de ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:24.04.23) ...
Paramétrage de linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-44-generic (6.8.0-44.44) ...
Paramétrage de libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 (2:1.02.185-3ubuntu3.1) ...
Paramétrage de dmsetup (2:1.02.185-3ubuntu3.1) ...
Paramétrage de libtiff6:amd64 (4.5.1+git230720-4ubuntu2.2) ...
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04 :
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04 dépend de linux-headers-6.8.0-44-generic; cependant :
 Le paquet linux-headers-6.8.0-44-generic n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04 (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Paramétrage de libcryptsetup12:amd64 (2:2.7.0-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Aucun rapport « apport » n'a été créé car le message d'erreur indique une erreur consécutive à un échec précédent.
                                                                                                                  Paramétrage de linux-tools-common (6.8.0-44.44) ...
Paramétrage de linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic (6.8.0-44.44) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.8.0-44-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.8.0-44-generic
Paramétrage de initramfs-tools-bin (0.142ubuntu25.2) ...
Paramétrage de cryptsetup-bin (2:2.7.0-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Paramétrage de linux-image-generic (6.8.0-44.44) ...
Paramétrage de libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64 (2.44.3-0ubuntu0.24.04.1) ...
Paramétrage de linux-tools-6.8.0-44 (6.8.0-44.44) ...
Paramétrage de libdevmapper-event1.02.1:amd64 (2:1.02.185-3ubuntu3.1) ...
Paramétrage de linux-tools-6.8.0-44-generic (6.8.0-44.44) ...
Paramétrage de cryptsetup (2:2.7.0-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Paramétrage de libwebkitgtk-6.0-4:amd64 (2.44.3-0ubuntu0.24.04.1) ...
Paramétrage de gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-6.0:amd64 (2.44.3-0ubuntu0.24.04.1) ...
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de linux-headers-generic :
 linux-headers-generic dépend de linux-headers-6.8.0-44-generic; cependant :
 Le paquet linux-headers-6.8.0-44-generic n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet linux-headers-generic (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Aucun rapport « apport » n'a été créé car le message d'erreur indique une erreur consécutive à un échec précédent.
                                                                                                                  Paramétrage de gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.1:amd64 (2.44.3-0ubuntu0.24.04.1) ...
Paramétrage de gir1.2-webkit-6.0:amd64 (2.44.3-0ubuntu0.24.04.1) ...
Paramétrage de initramfs-tools-core (0.142ubuntu25.2) ...
Paramétrage de initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu25.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Paramétrage de gir1.2-webkit2-4.1:amd64 (2.44.3-0ubuntu0.24.04.1) ...
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de linux-generic :
 linux-generic dépend de linux-headers-generic (= 6.8.0-44.44); cependant :
 Le paquet linux-headers-generic n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet linux-generic (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Paramétrage de ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (1:24.04.23) ...
Aucun rapport « apport » écrit car MaxReports a déjà été atteint
                                                                Paramétrage de cryptsetup-initramfs (2:2.7.0-1ubuntu4.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Paramétrage de liblvm2cmd2.03:amd64 (2.03.16-3ubuntu3.1) ...
Paramétrage de dmeventd (2:1.02.185-3ubuntu3.1) ...
dm-event.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Paramétrage de lvm2 (2.03.16-3ubuntu3.1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour libc-bin (2.39-0ubuntu8.3) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic (6.8.0-44.44) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-44-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-44-generic all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/6.8.0-44-generic/build/include KVERSION=6.8.0-44-generic DKMS_BUILD=1...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for evdi: 1.10.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-44-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.10.1/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-44-generic/x86_64 failed for evdi(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-44-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic (--configure) :
 le sous-processus paquet linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic script post-installation installé a renvoyé un état de sortie d'erreur 11
Aucun rapport « apport » écrit car MaxReports a déjà été atteint
                                                                Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu25.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 linux-headers-6.8.0-44-generic
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)



For the new kernel 6.8.0.44 the dkms cannot build the drivers for the devices installed in the dkms. Can you run 'dkms status' to identify the modules you have installed in the dkms and for which kernels. Please append the result to your question (or your answer if you are using it to report a similar problem). You might also like to investigate to find our it a new driver is available for the later kernel that you could install.

In my case, thanks to david comment, I ran dkms status command and find out that I had two Anbox Android kernel modules installed (maybe installed in the past with some emulator, I don't know...):
anbox-ashmem/1
anbox-binder/1
Then I executed dkms remove anbox-ashmem and dkms remove anbox-binder as root, launched the upgrade again and this time worked fine.
Hope this helps

$ dkms status
amdgpu/6.7.0-1787201.22.04, 6.8.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed. Meaning ?

The amdgpu/6.7.0-1787201.22.04  (MI100 GPU device) is a locally built (by the dkms) driver for the listed Graphics Processor (GPU) for the 6.8.0-40-generic kernel. The dkms will rebuild (or attempt to) the driver whenever the kernel changes. Your current kernel is given with the command 'uname -r'.

The amdgpu issue is being discussed on GitHub. . .
